# Comment engine for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, comments

I am developing my own blog website in asp.net. I wonder if anything like this exists, which I could place like a script inside each of my blog page and will work as a comment. Might be a third party tool, which will allow me to moderate comment before posting them.
Which also has login feature may be from facebook, google, twitter, open id. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **[Disqus](http://disqus.com/)**? Its quite popular recently.

It basically takes away all your worries on maintaining your own comment system.

Hope this is helpful,